# Deserializing XML to object raises System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have serialized a `PrinterSettings` to a string using an `XMLSerializer`.

Now when I try to deserialize the string to a `PrinterSettings`, I'm getting a

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error in XML-Document (10,4). The value may not be NULL.

I have compared the serialized and the deserialized string, they are perfectly the same, so there must be something wrong with the way I try to deserialize it.

Does anybody see my mistake?

```vb
Dim nPrint As New PrinterSettings
Dim sTest As String = String.Empty

Dim nXSer1 As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PrinterSettings))
Using sw As New StringWriter
    nXSer1.Serialize(sw, nPrint)
    sTest = sw.ToString()
End Using

'just a test to see if it would work
Dim nXSer2 As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PrinterSettings))
Using sr As TextReader = New StringReader(sTest)
    Try
        nPrint = nXSer2.Deserialize(sr) 'raises error Error in XML-Document (10,4). The value may not be NULL.
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Assert(False)
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: The 10,4 indicates it is on line 10 character 4 of the xml file.  Are you de-serialing the file that was serialized?  the only time I've seen issue with deserialzing an xml that came from a serialization is when the namespaces did not match.

Comment: @jdweng I have edited my post and inserted the string (it's the same both serialized and deserialized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintToFilename may not be empty. When I fill it with an arbitrary string, it works.
However, the XML serialization of the printer setting missed many elements that wouldn't be missed if serialized using a binaryserializer, which is what I do now:

```
Private Function SettingToString(ByVal settings As PrinterSettings) As String
    If settings Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim bf = New BinaryFormatter()

    Using ms = New MemoryStream()
        bf.Serialize(ms, settings)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
    End Using
End Function

Private Function SettingFromString(ByVal base64 As String) As PrinterSettings
    Try
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()

        Using ms = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64))
            Return CType(bf.Deserialize(ms), PrinterSettings)
        End Using

    Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        Return New PrinterSettings()
    End Try
End Function
```